# Parsley.js Validation Requirement

Tags: parsley.js

Good afternoon all! I am looking for some guidance to see if this type of validation is possible. I work for a college and am using a form that pushes to our CRM when complete. I am looking for parsley to only validate the email address field IF they enter their college email address. Is this possible? I am trying to weave out personal email accounts and keep everything uniform with the same email address.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you have two different email fields? In general the answer is that you can validate whatever you want with Parsley, some things are just harder to do than others.

Comment: There are two email addresses that I want to accept - one for students and one for faculty, however, both contain the same domain so as long as the main domain is validated, it won't matter. I hope this makes sense. In short, I only want to allow email addresses that contain the text "walshcollege.edu".

Answer (score 1):

You can do that e.g. by using [`data-parsley-pattern`](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-validator-pattern) and defining a pattern that matches only the required mail addresses. The pattern to validate against the mail addresses you mentioned in your comment might look like this:

```
.*@(mail\.)?walshcollege.edu$
```

This matches everything that:

- Starts with any number (`*`) of arbitrary characters (`.`)
- Followed by an @
- Might be followed by "mail.". The dot is escaped to avoid the special meaning "any character", the question mark means "might be there or not" and the parentheses make the question apply to the complete string.
- Ends with walscollege.edu (the $ means the end of the string)

If you also want to make sure that an mail address is inserted you need to add [`data-parsley-required`](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-validator-required) as Parsley by default does not validate empty fields.

Also keep in mind that Parsley validation is only client side, so you should add validations in the server to really make sure that no wrong mail address is used.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So in this instance, I want to validate only email addresses that have [at]walshcollege.edu and [at]mail.walshcollege.edu. In this instance, we can probably just select to validate "walshcollege.edu" because it is contained in both of those email addresses. How would a pattern be set up for this?

Comment: @GeoffreyWeed I've edited the answer with information how the pattern might look like.